# The "access_key" option must be provided to use fixer.io

Tags: php, laravel, fixer.io

For the currency conversion i am using "florianv/laravel-swap": "^1.1" library. [Florianv/Laravel-swap](https://github.com/florianv/laravel-swap).

As Fixer.io has changed its implementation, it is necessary to pass the access_key with the request, and because of that i am getting this error: "InvalidArgumentException: The "access_key" option must be provided to use fixer.io in **/var/www/project/project-files/vendor/florianv/exchanger/src/Service/Fixer.php:51**".

I registered and got the access_key.
I updated the library using composer and now i can see three constants in the **vendor/florianv/exchanger/src/Service/Fixer.php**.

```
const ACCESS_KEY_OPTION = 'access_key';
const LATEST_URL = 'http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?base=%s&access_key=%s';
const HISTORICAL_URL = 'http://data.fixer.io/api/%s?base=%s&access_key=%s';
```

To pass the access key i tried this:

I have a swap.php in config folder which looks something like this:

```
return [
    'options' => [
        'cache_ttl' => 86400, // 24 hours.
        'cache_key_prefix' => 'currency_rate'
    ],
    'services' => [
        'fixer' => true,
    ],
    'currency_layer' => [
        'access_key' => 'asdfas7832mw3nsdfa776as8dfa', // Your app id
        'enterprise' => true, // True if your AppId is an enterprise one
    ],
    'cache' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'file'),
    'http_client' => null,
    'request_factory' => null,
    'cache_item_pool' => null,
];
```

This had one more option which was commented, i enabled and passed the access_key in it but it doesn't work.
I also added it in services block below 'fixer => true'.

```
'currency_layer' => [
    'access_key' => 'asdfas7832mw3nsdfa776as8dfa'
]
```

Also in options block:

```
'options' => [
    'cache_ttl' => 86400, // 24 hours.
    'cache_key_prefix' => 'currency_rate',
    'access_key'=>'7ca208e9136c5e140d6a14427bf9ed21'
],
```

I tried with adding access_key in config/services.php file but it also didn't work.

```
'fixer' => [
    'access_key'     => 'asdfas7832mw3nsdfa776as8dfa'
],
```

Even i tried, adding to env file and calling from there, but no success. How do i pass the access_key, can anyone help me on this, what should be the approach.

Answer (score 0):

vendor/florianv/exchanger/src/Service/Fixer.php -> **don't touch the constant** (that was my own error).

Pass the options-array by creating the Builder:

```
    $options = ['access_key'    => 'YourGeneratedAPIKeyAtCurrencyLayer'];
    $this->exchangeSwap = (new Builder($options))
      ->add('fixer', $options )
      ->build();
```

I hope I could help ;-)